# Show Selected/Stored Image on Android After Reset/Kill the App

Tags: android, image, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to show the image that a user selected either through camera or from image gallery. The app should show this image even after the app is 
restarted/killed and persist.

I attempted to do this by checking on 
`onCreate()`, if there was a file where the app can check to see what image it 
needs to display and if not, show a default image to indicate a profile 
picture should be selected by user.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.pickimagetakeexamples

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var btn: Button? = null
    private var imageview: ImageView? = null
    private val GALLERY = 1
    private val CAMERA = 2

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

        btn = findViewById<View>(R.id.btn) as Button
        imageview = findViewById<View>(R.id.iv) as ImageView

        val wallpaperDirectory = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY)

        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
        {

        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/wallpaperDirectory"))

        } else {

            val img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.profile_image)
            val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, img)
            round.isCircular = true
            iv.setImageDrawable(round)
            println("Image_Directory")
            println(IMAGE_DIRECTORY)

        }

        btn!!.setOnClickListener { showPictureDialog() }

    }

    private fun showPictureDialog() {
        val pictureDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action")
        val pictureDialogItems = arrayOf("Select Photo From Gallery", "Capture Photo From Camera")
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems
        ) { dialog, which ->
            when (which) {
                0 -> choosePhotoFromGallary()
                1 -> takePhotoFromCamera()
            }
        }
        pictureDialog.show()
    }

    fun choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)
    }

    fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA)
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data: Intent?) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == GALLERY)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                val contentURI = data.data
                try
                {
                    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, contentURI)
                    val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, bitmap)
                    round.isCircular = true

                    val path = saveImage(bitmap)
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    imageview!!.setImageDrawable(round)

                }
                catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == CAMERA)
        {
            val thumbnail = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
            val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, thumbnail)
            round.isCircular = true
            imageview!!.setImageDrawable(round)
            saveImage(thumbnail)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
    }

    fun saveImage(myBitmap: Bitmap):String {
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes)
        val wallpaperDirectory = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY)
        println("WallpaperDirectory::" + wallpaperDirectory)

        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        Log.d("fee",wallpaperDirectory.toString())
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
        {

            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs()
        }

        try
        {
            Log.d("heel",wallpaperDirectory.toString())
            val f = File(wallpaperDirectory, ((Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis()).toString() + ".jpg"))
            f.createNewFile()
            val fo = FileOutputStream(f)
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    arrayOf(f.getPath()),
                    arrayOf("image/jpeg"), null)
            fo.close()
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath())

            return f.getAbsolutePath()
        }
        catch (e1: IOException) {
            e1.printStackTrace()
        }

        return ""
    }

    companion object {
        private val IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts"

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--        android:text="Select or Capture Image" -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:width="2dp"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@mipmap/profile_image" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add this line before to save the image to have only one image saved:

```
val wallpaperDirectory = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY)
wallpaperDirectory.deleteRecursively()
```

Then if the image exist you can get the absolutePath of the image saved in your directory and show the imagen.
Replace with this code:

```
    val wallpaperDirectory = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY)

    var listImages : Array<File>? = null
    listImages = wallpaperDirectory.listFiles()

    if(listImages != null && listImages.size!! > 0){
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listImages[0].absolutePath))
    }
    else {
        val img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.profile_image)
        val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, img)
        round.isCircular = true
        iv.setImageDrawable(round)
        println("Image_Directory")
        println(IMAGE_DIRECTORY)
    }
```